# How do I remove NaN values from my category type columns? I used .dropna but it doesn't work

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[image]

I want to remove the NaN values from Dep Freq & Sex Orien. I used .dropna and get this result [image]

How do I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: try `.dropna()`

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html has detailed info but you're invoking a method so you need () with your parameters in need.

Answer (score 1):

According to the pandas.DataFrame.dropna documentation, dropna method is used to completely drop the columns or rows. Are you going to drop completely columns with existing Nan values? Or what do you mean by “I want to remove Nan values”?

Comment: Yes I would like to completely remove them

Answer (score 0):

Try this to drop the Nan value columns

```
df.dropna(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you  can find more info on how to call `dropna()` method at [pandas.DataFrame.dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and below listing example of usage with row if does have missing and columns  drop if any contains `NaN` so resulting is empty dataframe since all cols does have missing:

```
In [4]: import pandas as pd

In [5]: import numpy as np

In [6]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), index=['a', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'h'],columns=['one', 'two', 'three'])

In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
        one       two     three
a -1.040103  1.964200  1.519638
c -0.796710  1.654887 -0.614065
e  1.899870  0.810478  1.294714
f -0.913869  1.052014 -0.114583
h  0.186190 -0.156173 -2.323759

In [8]: df2 = df.reindex(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'])

In [9]: df2
Out[9]: 
        one       two     three
a -1.040103  1.964200  1.519638
b       NaN       NaN       NaN
c -0.796710  1.654887 -0.614065
d       NaN       NaN       NaN
e  1.899870  0.810478  1.294714
f -0.913869  1.052014 -0.114583
g       NaN       NaN       NaN
h  0.186190 -0.156173 -2.323759

In [10]: df2.dropna()
Out[10]: 
        one       two     three
a -1.040103  1.964200  1.519638
c -0.796710  1.654887 -0.614065
e  1.899870  0.810478  1.294714
f -0.913869  1.052014 -0.114583
h  0.186190 -0.156173 -2.323759

In [11]: df2.dropna(axis="columns")
Out[11]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]

In [12]: df2
Out[12]: 
        one       two     three
a -1.040103  1.964200  1.519638
b       NaN       NaN       NaN
c -0.796710  1.654887 -0.614065
d       NaN       NaN       NaN
e  1.899870  0.810478  1.294714
f -0.913869  1.052014 -0.114583
g       NaN       NaN       NaN
h  0.186190 -0.156173 -2.323759

In [13]: df2.dropna(inplace=True)

In [14]: df2
Out[14]: 
        one       two     three
a -1.040103  1.964200  1.519638
c -0.796710  1.654887 -0.614065
e  1.899870  0.810478  1.294714
f -0.913869  1.052014 -0.114583
h  0.186190 -0.156173 -2.323759
```

#### if you look to drop observations or columns in specific columns:

```
In [26]: df2[['one','three']].dropna(axis='columns')
Out[26]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]

In [27]: df2[['one','three']].dropna(axis=0)
Out[27]: 
        one     three
a -1.040103  1.519638
c -0.796710 -0.614065
e  1.899870  1.294714
f -0.913869 -0.114583
h  0.186190 -2.323759
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the replace( ) function**

```
df.replace('NaN', 'Word XY')
```

#### Example

**Table with NaN**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
['1', 'Fares', 32, True],
['2', 'Elena', 23, 'NaN'],
['NaN', 'Steven', 40, True],
['4', 'Max', 24, 'NaN'],
['5', 'Mike', 20, False],
['NaN', 'John', 40, True]])

df.columns = ['id', 'name', 'age', 'decision']

df
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Now use the replace function( )**

```
df.replace('NaN', ' ')
```

**Desired Output:**

[image]

So what this does is simply replace the string 'NaN' with an empty whitespace. You can add whatever word you want for the replacement.

df.replace('NaN', '######') would replace every NaN with number signs.

I hope I could help you a bit.